# Где можно поменять слово Price:, на русское Цена?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как и где перевести Price: на русский вариант?
В functions.php не нашла.

Answer (score 3):

Woocommerce полностью переведён на русский. https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce/dev/ru/default

Если перевод не подтянулся - значит есть проблемы на сервере и их нужно решать. А пока можно скачать лангпак (*.mo *.po) с вышеуказанного места и положить в `/wp-content/languages/plugins/` с именами `woocommerce-ru_RU.*`.

Если же это слово берется из темы, то лучше перевести в теме.
В данном случае перевод этого слова есть и можно аналогично скачать лангпак [отсюда](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-themes/estore/ru/default), поместив в `/wp-content/languages/themes/`. (Кроме того любой может поучаствовать в переводе тем и плагинов. См [тут](https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD/))

В крайнем случае можно также использовать рекомендованный разработчиками плагин [Say What](https://wordpress.org/plugins/say-what/). См https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-localization/#section-10

Comment: У неё в теме эта цена

Comment: В теме она тоже переведена. :) Я ж и ссылку на ланпак дал.

Comment: да понятно, плюсанул. Уточнил просто.

Comment: Спс, Я и ответ сейчас чуть уточнил.

Answer (score 0):

Анна, вам нужно установить плагин локализации и с его помощью переименовать https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/